# Why can't I send to more than one address using AWS SDK sendEmail?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I started implementing the AWS SDK into our application to send emails.  I increased our limit through AWS to get out of the sandbox so that I could start sending emails to other people.  The problem I'm noticing is that if I have more than one address in my `recipient` variable that I get this error: `Illegal Address`.  Both email addresses are in the form `name@domain.com`.  I've tested sending to each email individually and both work just fine, but as soon as I put both addresses into the recipient variable I get the `Illegal Address` error.  My only assumption is that having more than one recipient is causing the issue, but if this is the problem then why does their documentation say that there can be multiple addresses included?

Here is my code

```
if ((request.url).substring(0, 5) == "/send") {

        var mailOptions = {
            to: request.query.to,
            bcc: request.query.bcc,
            subject: request.query.subject,
            text: request.query.text
        }

        console.log(mailOptions.to);

        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: env.AWS.ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: env.AWS.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: 'someregion'
        });

        const sender = "noreply@domain.com";
        const recipient = mailOptions.to; // this includes "name@domain.com, name2@domain.com"
        const subject = mailOptions.subject;
        const body_html = mailOptions.text;
        const charset = "UTF-8";

        const ses = new AWS.SES();
        var params = { 
            Source: sender, 
            Destination: { 
              ToAddresses: [
                recipient
              ],
              BccAddresses: [
                sender
              ],
            },
            Message: {
              Subject: {
                Data: subject,
                Charset: charset
              },
              Body: {
                Html: {
                  Data: body_html,
                  Charset: charset
                }
              }
            }
          };

          ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
            // If something goes wrong, print an error message.
            if(err) {
              console.log(err.message);
            } else {
              console.log("Email sent! Message ID: ", data.MessageId);
            }
          });
```

If anyone knows why this is happening and knows what I need to do to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723411/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-through-aws-ses) solve your problem?

Comment: @varontron it gives me some ideas but I'm still trying to make it work.

Comment: is `recipient` an Array of strings like `["name@domain.com", "name2@domain.com"]` or just a single string as in your comment?  It needs to be an Array, as noted in the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_Destination.html)

Comment: @varontron it seemed to be a single string.  I decided to split the string by comma and then loop through that object and push to an array.  I think this is kind of a messed up way to go about this unless there is an easier way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals, but imagine this process at scale. If you were emailing 100k address, you'd have those in a database. Your query results would more likely be in a data structure, and not joined in a string, and you wouldn't want to take the resources (time, memory, etc) to join them--potentially even exceeding the maximum string length or argument length of some environments.

Comment: Also, isn't there a `split` command that returns an array?

Comment: you can use split like this `"a,b".split(",") => [ 'a', 'b' ]` , here you are splitting by comma and it will be give you an array.